# 4 divs with 40% width of viewport with overflow-x

Tags: html, css

I have the following issue. Based on resulotion, basically for mobile view i want still to have 4 divs but i want them 40% of viewport, so i will have 2 and a half div visible and 1 and a half should be overflown with scroll available.

i tried something like this:

```
#bsp-content {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    @media all and (max-width: $mobile_breakpoint){
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

    .bsp-container:last-child {
        @include set_solid_border(0,$acc_grey,right);        
    }

    .bsp-container {
        width: 25%;
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        @include set_solid_border(1,$acc_grey,right);
        > div {
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        }
        @media all and (max-width: $mobile_breakpoint) {
            width: 40%;
        }
    }
```

where content is actually viewport and container is div (there are 4 of them).

Can anybody give me a hint please?

Note: I dont want to use javascript to recalculate viewport, and also i dont want to have them fixed width.

Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE - html part

```
<div id="bsp-content" ">
  <div class="bsp-container">
    <img src="img1"/>
    <div>text1</div>
  </div>    
  <div class="bsp-container">
    <img src="img2"/>
    <div>text2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bsp-container">
    <img src="img3"/>
    <div>text3</div>
  </div>
    <div class="bsp-container">
      <img src="img4"/>
      <div>text4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html part?

Comment: i just did. I will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use `width: 40vw;` instead of `width: 40%;`.